# How to inject field name and its value into method at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net

I wish this isn't a duplicate or maybe there is a simpler solution. To the point:
In my project I created a handler I would like to generically Validate DB data in a way that I inject it into specific handler, lets say like this:

```
        public AddSomethingHandler(
        IRepository<Something> repository,
        IMappingService mappingService,
        IRandomizeObjectService randomizeObjectService,
        IHandlerValidation<Something> handlerValidation
        )
        : base(
              repository,
              mappingService,
              randomizeObjectService,
              handlerValidation)
    {
    }
```

As you can see it is called *IHandlerValidation*.
And now in *AddSthngHandler* body my goal is to call my Validator

```
        public SomethingDto Handle(AddSomethingAction action)
    {
        _handlerValidation.ValidateExistance(action.SomethingCode);
    }
```

And here is the trick, I would like to inject into *ValidateExistance* method also the name of field *SomethingCode* along with its value.
Why I would to do it?
Because I would like to extract Validation logic outside my handler and perform any required actions in a generic way to serve other handlers needs.

Help?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in your example you want to have the value of the `SomethingCode` variable as well as a string with the value "SomethingCode" passed into the ValidateExistance? What do you expect to gain from this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public SomethingDto Handle(AddSomethingAction action)
{
    _handlerValidation.ValidateExistance(action.SomethingCode, nameof(AddSomethingAction.SomethingCode));
}
```

Note, that `nameof` keyword available only from C# 6.0.

Comment: That sounds nice:) it for sure makes parameter much cleaner in comparison to the one I created in the backyard, however it is still not that user friendly. I am just wondering if there is anything a bit more compact. Anyway I really appreciate your help Yuriy!:)

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do it more compact, although you can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information), may it helps you.